# Pass data to the twitter modal

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

Hello i want to pass my `news_id` to the twitter modal. But im getting a wrong data Can someone give me ideas on how to pass a data to the modal?

i delete the news with news_id "29"
[image]

and the deleted data is news with news_id "28"
[image]

here is my code.

```
  <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-bordered" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="60">ID</th>
                    <th width="200">News Title</th>
                    <th width="150">Date Posted</th>
                    <th>Content</th>
                    <th width="200">Image</th>
                    <th width="200">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php

            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY news_id");
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['news_id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['news_title']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['news_date']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['news_content']; ?></td>
                    <td><img style="height:150px; width:200px;" src="<?php echo $row['news_image']; ?>"  ></td>
                    <td>
                         <a class='btn btn-info left-margin' href="edit2.php?newsid=<?php echo $row['news_id'];?>" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a>
                         <a class='btn btn-danger delete-object' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</a>

                                 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                                     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                         <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                 Are you sure you want to delete this?
                                            </div>
                                         <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <a class='btn btn-danger left-margin' href="delete.php?newsid=<?php echo $row['news_id'];?>" >Yes</a>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                     </div>
                                </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

here is my delete.php

```
<?php
include_once('connection.php');
$newsid = $_GET['newsid'];

if(isset($newsid)){
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "DELETE FROM news WHERE news_id = ?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $newsid);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        header('location: edit.php');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error resides in the way you declare your modals.

Your first delete button for news_id 28 opens the modal with the id `#myModal`, but so does the second button for news_id 29, which opens the first modal with id `#myModal`, being the modal for news_id 28.

Proposed solution: Add the ID to the modal.

`<a class='btn btn-danger delete-object' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal<?php echo $row['news_id'];?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</a>`

and

`<div class="modal fade" id="modal<?php echo $row['news_id'];?>" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">`

should fix it.

Comment: My god! Your my hero @Chris senpai :D Thankyou master.

Comment: sir? can we move to a chat?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to offer personal support.